# How to Give Send on Behalf Permission on a Distribution Group to several mailboxes

Tags: exchange-2010

I have one Distribution Group **TestDG** and three mailboxes **mb01**, **mb02**, **mb03**. I want to give Send on Behalf Permission on a Distribution Group to these 3 mailboxes.

I've tried to set it like below for every mailbox but next one always overrides the previous one.

```
Set-DistributionGroup "TestDG" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo mb01
Set-DistributionGroup "TestDG" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo mb02
Set-DistributionGroup "TestDG" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo mb03
```

Is it possible to give this permission to multiple mailboxes? if there is a way to do this I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: "Send On Behalf" and "Send As" are ***not*** the same thing, which one are you interested in?

Comment: Thanks for this remark! I appreciate it! I've fixed my question. So, I'm interested in Send on Behalf!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Technet documentation for the `Set-DistributionGroup` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124955(v=exchg.141).aspx), the `GrantSendOnBehalfTo` parameter takes an argument of type **Microsoft.Exchange.Data.MultiValuedProperty**.

As outlined by PowerShell MVP Shay Levy in [this article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/scriptfanatic/2010/11/22/managing-email-addresses-in-exchange-2010/), any **MultiValuedProperty** can take partial updates in the form of a HashTable containing values that you want to **Add** or **Remove**, like so:

```
Set-DistributionGroup "TestDG" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{"Add"="mb01","mb02"}
Set-DistributionGroup "TestDG" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{"Add"="mb03"}
```

Each update will add the target to the list of "Send on Behalf" grantees, without overwriting the previous values.

Similarly, you can remove single values with the same technique:

```
Set-DistributionGroup "TestDG" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{"Remove"="mb02"}
```